# Ant System Class Loader does not honor $CLASSPATH, honors $LOCALCLASSPATH

Tags: ant, classpath, classloader

I am implementing an ant task as a wrapper for another class, which loads other several classes using the system class loader. Now, the task is in the same jar of these other classes, so I wonder why it is not finding them, since the task *is* running

Please notice that my classes are in the `$CLASSPATH` env variable. The problem will not occur if I `export LOCALCLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH`

Minimal example:

```
<taskdef name="mytask" classname="my.package.MyTask"  />

<target name="compile">
    <mytask />
</target>
```

you can easily see the problem here

```
public class MyTask extends Task {
   public void execute() throws BuildException {
    try {
        ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        // this will only print the ant jar file path
        for(URL url: ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs()){
        log(url.getFile());
        }

        cl.loadClass("my.package.OtherClass"); // throws an exception

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new BuildException(ex);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Is your problem related to 'delegating classloaders'  : http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#delegating-classloader

Comment: As far as I can tell, no

Comment: Hm, LOCALCLASSPATH copies valies from CLASSPATH.   Please add ant version, os version to your question. It could help some one.

Comment: OS X 10.8 /usr/bin/ant [ Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012 ] (should be the default installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ant` shell script reworks the classpath internally, so the SystemClassLoader contains only a minimal part of the "real" classpath

tl;dr: use

```
    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

instead of

```
    ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
```

From the Mailing List, [Rainer Noack](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/201303.mbox/browser):

> if you're launching ant via shell script, it is using 
>   oata.launcher.Launcher.java
>
> This class reorganises the classpath a bit. The env variable CLASSPATH
>   and the classpath commandline argument are  stripped and replaced by
>   the minimum classpath used to launch ant. A child classloader of the
>   system classloader is created with the  original CLASSPATH entries.
>   The oata.Project is then loaded with this classloader.

The problem is that the loader in `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` is actually untouched, the one that changes (i.e., the one that honors $CLASSPATH, -lib, etc.) can be retrieved using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`.